# Test in if condition makefile on cygwin

Tags: makefile, cygwin

I am trying to make the simplest comparison within an if condition in a makefile.
I am using cygwin. I keep getting the error **`XX was unexpected at this time`**. Where `XX` is the LHS of the comparison operator. This exact makefile runs on mks, but now I have to use cygwin because I am running it on a 64 bit windows at the moment.

Here is my code:

```
DEBUG=0

all:
    if test $(DEBUG) != 0 then\
        echo "not equal to 0"\
    fi
```

I also tried this:

```
DEBUG=0

all:
    if [ $(DEBUG) != 0 ] then\
        echo "not equal to 0"\
    fi
```

and this:

```
DEBUG=0

all:
    if [ "$(DEBUG)" != "0" ] then\
        echo "not equal to 0"\
    fi
```

This is the error:

`0 was unexpected at this time. *** [all] Error 255`

====================================================
Updates:

I have tried adding the missing `;` and also making it a one liner as @Jonas. suggested but still getting the same problem.

One Liner:

```
if [ $(DEBUG) != 0 ] ; then echo "not equal to 0" ; fi
```

With semicolons:

```
if [ $(DEBUG) != 0 ] ; then \
    echo "not equal to 0" ; \
fi
```

And yes I am using tabs not spaces. And I have changed the line endings to `LF` only.

Comment: Shell statements want a `;` at end.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It didn't work

Comment: You might want to explain what you are trying to do rather than what your attempted solution is. See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I want the script to run with no errors.. and I have said that.

Comment: You haven't said what your *original* problem is, all you've given is a trivial example that has no use in the real world. If you explain what you are trying to solve it might lead to a better answer.

Comment: I am sorry, but you are completely wrong. I have said that my problem is that my make produces this error. And about the code being trivial is because I have narrowed it down to this which is causing the error. I can easily copy my 800 lines make file and you won't help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two `;`. Without the last semicolon then `fi` is a parameter to `echo`. It works with: GNU Make 4.0 on Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64.

Note: There may be issues when using older versions of GNU Make.

```
DEBUG=1

all:
    if [ $(DEBUG) != 0 ]; then \
        echo "not equal to 0" ; \
    fi
```

Comment: Please remember to use tabs instead of spaces, I'm using: GNU Make 4.0 and it works

Comment: I am using tabs and GNU Make version 3.75 on cygwin on Windows XP 64 bit SP2

Comment: Should it be like this? `if [ $(DEBUG) != 0 ] ; then ; echo "not equal to 0" ; fi ;`

Comment: One semicolon too much, after `then`, that is: `if [ $(DEBUG) != 0 ] ; then echo "not equal to 0" ; fi`

Comment: Still giving me 0 was unexpected at this time.

Comment: which terminal are you using? (sorry, I'm not familiar with cygwin and windows)

Comment: cygwin_tcsh.bat

Comment: Can you try bash instead of tcsh?

Comment: I tried bash it doesn't show anything at all it just runs doesn't echo anything and doesn't show any errors. I verified that it works tho by echoing before the if condition and it does echo.

Comment: I have upgraded to using make 4.0 and then 4.2 now and both of them work. I guess this was the problem. Thanks a lot for the help man

Comment: Great. Please accept an answer, if it answers your question

Comment: Yes I want to accept it as an answer. But would you please edit it and show that it's the old version that is causing the problem. So that anyone who have the same problem would know what to do exactly.

Comment: GNU make _3.75_?!?!  Holy <diety>!  That's over 20 years old!  I had no idea any binary that old still existed.  Anyway, my suspicion is that your makefile was written using DOS-style line endings (CRLF) instead of UNIX-style line endings (LF).  Up until GNU make 3.78 (released Sep 1999) make didn't do any special handling of CRLF.

Comment: Well, yeah such things still exist on legacy projects built 10 years ago or so. And yes this was one of my first steps that is changing CRLF to LF but that didn't do it. Newer make version was the solution.